# data reader has rows but comparison of its values is never true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a module for booking rooms in hotel.After selecting the rooms, the room numbers appear in a label. On clicking the OK button, the following code executes. When I am checking the availability of rooms, even if it is "No", flag does'nt get initialized to 1. Can anyone guide me where am I going wrong.

```cs
protected void ok_room(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Label1.Text != "")
    {
        int result = 0;
        int flag = 0;

        string[] room = Label1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd1.Connection = con;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        for (int i = 0; i < room.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd1.CommandText = "select room_availability from rooms where room_num='" + room[i] + "'  ";
            dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (dr[0].ToString().Equals("No"))//this is not working
                    flag = 1;
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        Response.Write(flag);
        if (flag == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < room.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "update rooms set room_availability='No' where room_num='" + room[i] + "'";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                result = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label2.Text = "Some of the selected rooms are not available. Kindly try again";
            Label1.Visible=false;
        }
        if (result == 1)
        {
            isRoomAvailable = true;
            Label2.Text = " Room(s) " + Label1.Text + " is/are booked";
            Label1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    else
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Select a room first.')</script>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I would do more of the logic in SQL, this would simplify the code:

// Create a condition looking like this: room_num IN('1', '2', '3')
string roomsCondition = "room_num IN (' + Label1.Text.Replace(" ", "', '") + "')";

cmd1.CommandText =
    @"SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN room_availability='Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As available,
    SUM(CASE WHEN room_availability='No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As not_available
    FROM rooms WHERE " + roomsCondition;
```

This query returns the number of available and non available rooms. It should then be easier to formulate the logic than by the use of flags.

Also have a look at the `ExecuteScalar` method. It makes it even easier than with the query I have shown above:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
    string sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rooms WHERE room_availability='Yes' AND " +
                 roomsCondition;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();
    int availableRooms = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (availableRooms > 0) {
        cmd.CommandText =
            @"UPDATE rooms
            SET room_availability='No'
            WHERE availability='Yes' AND " + roomsCondition;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi....Thanks for this answer. But I am a really new person in this field, and finding this solution a bit hard. Is there any other simper way to do this. And if I follow  my code, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Actually you need only my second example. It gives you the number of available rooms with `(int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();`. The method `ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row. That's easier than `while (dr.Read()) { if (dr[0].ToString().Equals "No")) flag = 1; ...`! If you want to know what's going wrong, [debug](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging)! Set a breakpoint on the non-working row and see what value `dr[0].ToString()` returns.